# MongoDB query. Match each element from array of objects (ad conditions)?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have articles in db and I need to get slugs for each of dates.

```
"eventDate" : {
    "day" : "21",
    "month" : "04"
},
"slug": "some-slug"
...
```

As and input I have `[{day: '01', month: '02'}, {day: '02', month: '02'}]` and I need to get all articles that match this.
I did something like this:

```
.find({'eventDate': { $in: myArrayOfObjects}}, {slug: 1})
```

How do I get it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use **`$in`** for searching object. In this case, you should use **`$or`** like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "eventDate.day": "01",
      "eventDate.month": "02"
    },
    {
      "eventDate.day": "02",
      "eventDate.month": "02"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "slug": 1
})
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/olTwcwGuuFi](https://mongoplayground.net/p/olTwcwGuuFi)

Comment: what do I do to get only top 1 for each date?